# The JFrame or the JPanel don't listen to the clicking event

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt, actionlistener

I have this JFrame(BorderLayout), that has 3 Jpanel in it(north, center, south).
The center panel, has a login button.
For testing purposes, what I want is to print "hello", when pressed.

This is how the frame currently looks:
[image]

I have tried 2 ways:

1. "implements ActionListener", on the center panel, but nothing happens, not even an error.
2. "implements ActionListener", on the frame itself, however, I am having issues (more like, I don't know how to) "importing"/having access to the button, so the JFrame can listen to the cliking event

Hope you can help me.

This is the code:

Main program:

```
package com.system.reservation.airline;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage(); 
    }
}
```

LoginPage:

```
import com.system.reservation.airline.panels.BodyPanel;
import com.system.reservation.airline.panels.FooterPanel;
import com.system.reservation.airline.panels.HeaderPanel;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class LoginPage extends JFrame{ 
    HeaderPanel headerPanel = new HeaderPanel();
    BodyPanel bodyPanel = new BodyPanel();
    FooterPanel footerPanel = new FooterPanel();

    public LoginPage(){ // Constructor
        this.setTitle("Login");
        this.setSize(400, 600);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        this.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(240,248,255));
        this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        this.add(headerPanel, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        this.add(bodyPanel, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.gridheight = 3;
        this.add(footerPanel, gbc);

        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

BodyPanel:

```
package com.system.reservation.airline.panels;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class BodyPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    JLabel login_label;
    JButton login_button = new JButton("Login");
    Color transparent = new Color(1f,0f,0f,0f);

    public BodyPanel(){
        this.setBackground(transparent);
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.green, 3));
        //------------ Login Panel ------------------------
        JPanel login_panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        login_panel.setBackground(transparent);
        login_panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 100));
        //login_panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.YELLOW, 5));

        login_label = new JLabel();
        login_label.setText("Login");
        login_label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        login_label.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));

        login_panel.add(login_label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        //------------ Login Panel ------------------------

        //------------ Input Panel ------------------------
        JPanel input_fields_panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        input_fields_panel.setBackground(transparent);
        input_fields_panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 150));
        //input_fields_panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 5));

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

        //-------------
        JLabel userName_label = new JLabel("Username: ");
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(0,10,0,0);
        input_fields_panel.add(userName_label, gbc);

        JTextField userName_txb = new JTextField();
        userName_txb.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250,30));
        gbc.gridx = 3;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(0,0,5,20);
        input_fields_panel.add(userName_txb, gbc);
        //-------------

        //-------------
        JLabel password_label = new JLabel("Password: ");
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(0,10,0,0);
        input_fields_panel.add(password_label, gbc);

        JTextField password_txb = new JTextField();
        password_txb.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250,30));
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 3;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5,0,5,20);
        input_fields_panel.add(password_txb, gbc);
        //-------------

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.gridwidth = 4;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5,150,5,150);
        input_fields_panel.add(login_button, gbc);

        JLabel tokenResponse = new JLabel("Username or password, are incorrect!");
        tokenResponse.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        gbc.gridwidth = 4;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(0,0,0,0);
        input_fields_panel.add(tokenResponse, gbc);
        //------------ Input Panel ------------------------

        //-------------------------------------
        this.add(login_panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.add(input_fields_panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == login_button) {
            System.out.println("Hello");
        }
    }
}
```

The center panel is the BodyPanel, hence I did not include the code for the HeaderPanel, or the FooterPanel.

So to recap, I want to either the LoginPage to have access or to listen to the clicking event of the login_button, or the exact same for the BodyPanel.

Comment: You never add an action listener to the JButton? Specifically `login_button.addActionListener(yourEvent);`

Comment: @sorifiend I think you mean the ActionListener.

Comment: 1) implementing an `ActionListener` does NOT register it to any component, it will not react on any action event unless added to a component; 2) "when pressed" - when WHAT is pressed? The center panel, the frame or the "Login" button? 3) `JFrame` and `JPanel` do not (by default) generate `ActionEvent` when clicked

Comment: Thanks all, that was it "login_button.addActionListener(this);"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to add an implementation of the `ActionListener` interface to your button.

The constructor should include something like this at some point:

```
public BodyPanel(){
   //...
   login_button.addActionListener(this);
   //...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The "obvious" problem is the fact that you've not registered an `ActionListener` to the `login_button`.  The less "obvious" problem is, what do you do with it when the `actionPerformed` method is called.

This is where an [observer pattern](https://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html) becomes important (you've already used one, `ActionListener` is a type of an observer pattern).

You need someway to know when the `BodyPanel` has authenticated the user.  To this end, I would add some kind of "login observer" to the `BodyPanel`, to which the `LoginPage` would register to, for example.

```
public interface LoginObserver {
    public void didAuthenticate(BodyPanel source, User user);
}
```

I might also consider using [Dependency Injection](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/a-quick-intro-to-dependency-injection-what-it-is-and-when-to-use-it-7578c84fa88f/) to define some kind of "authentication" workflow, which would be passed through `LoginPage` to `BodyPanel` to decouple the workflow, but that's probably getting beyond scope.

## Runnable example

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new LoginPage();
            }
        });
    }

    public interface User {
        public String getName();
    }

    public class DefaultUser implements User {
        private String name;

        public DefaultUser(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    }

    public class LoginPage extends JFrame {
//        HeaderPanel headerPanel = new HeaderPanel();
        BodyPanel bodyPanel = new BodyPanel(new BodyPanel.LoginObserver() {
            @Override
            public void didAuthenticate(BodyPanel source, User user) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(getContentPane(), "Welcome " + user.getName(), "Welcome", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            }
        });
//        FooterPanel footerPanel = new FooterPanel();

        public LoginPage() { // Constructor
            this.setTitle("Login");
            this.setSize(400, 600);
            this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            this.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(240, 248, 255));
            this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.gridheight = 1;
//            this.add(headerPanel, gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 1;
            gbc.gridheight = 1;
            this.add(bodyPanel, gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 2;
            gbc.gridheight = 3;
//            this.add(footerPanel, gbc);

            this.pack();
            this.setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    public class BodyPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
        private interface LoginObserver {
            public void didAuthenticate(BodyPanel source, User user);
        }

        JLabel login_label;
        JButton login_button = new JButton("Login");
        // This is VERY bad idea
        //Color transparent = new Color(1f, 0f, 0f, 0f);

        private JTextField userName_txb;
        private JPasswordField password_txb;
        private JLabel tokenResponse;

        private LoginObserver loginObserver;

        public BodyPanel(LoginObserver loginObserver) {
            this.loginObserver = loginObserver;
            //this.setBackground(transparent);
            setOpaque(false);
            this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.green, 3));
            //------------ Login Panel ------------------------
            JPanel login_panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
//            login_panel.setBackground(transparent);
            login_panel.setOpaque(false);
            // This is another BAD idea
//            login_panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 100));
            //login_panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.YELLOW, 5));

            login_label = new JLabel();
            login_label.setText("Login");
            login_label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            login_label.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));

            login_panel.add(login_label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            //------------ Login Panel ------------------------

            //------------ Input Panel ------------------------
            JPanel input_fields_panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
//            input_fields_panel.setBackground(transparent);
            input_fields_panel.setOpaque(false);
            // This is another BAD idea
//            input_fields_panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 150));
            //input_fields_panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 5));

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

            //-------------
            JLabel userName_label = new JLabel("Username: ");
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.gridwidth = 1;
            gbc.gridheight = 1;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 10, 0, 0);
            input_fields_panel.add(userName_label, gbc);

            userName_txb = new JTextField(10);
            //userName_txb.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 30));
            gbc.gridx = 3;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 20);
            input_fields_panel.add(userName_txb, gbc);
            //-------------

            //-------------
            JLabel password_label = new JLabel("Password: ");
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 1;
            gbc.gridwidth = 1;
            gbc.gridheight = 1;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 10, 0, 0);
            input_fields_panel.add(password_label, gbc);

            password_txb = new JPasswordField(10);
//            password_txb.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 30));
            gbc.gridx = 1;
            gbc.gridy = 1;
            gbc.gridwidth = 3;
            gbc.gridheight = 1;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 0, 5, 20);
            input_fields_panel.add(password_txb, gbc);
            //-------------

            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 2;
            gbc.gridwidth = 4;
            gbc.gridheight = 1;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 150, 5, 150);
            input_fields_panel.add(login_button, gbc);

            login_button.addActionListener(this);

            tokenResponse = new JLabel("Username or password, are incorrect!");
            tokenResponse.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 3;
            gbc.gridwidth = 4;
            gbc.gridheight = 1;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
            input_fields_panel.add(tokenResponse, gbc);
            //------------ Input Panel ------------------------

            //-------------------------------------
            this.add(login_panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            this.add(input_fields_panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (e.getSource() == login_button) {
                // Perform authentication via a seperate service
                loginObserver.didAuthenticate(this, new DefaultUser(userName_txb.getText()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Notes

Using transparent color (`Color transparent = new Color(1f, 0f, 0f, 0f);`) on Swing components is going to cause no end of issues.  Swing components are either fully opaque or fully transparent and this is controlled via the `opaque` property.

I would avoid using `setPreferredSize`, again, this is just going to cause you no end of issues.  Make use of the layout (`GridBagLayoutConstraints` provide a number of properties which can help adjust the spacing and size of the components), `EmptyBorder`s and, for text components, sizing hints via the `columns` property